# Does Azure SQL natively support being the subscriber in transactional replication where Oracle is the publisher?...and if PostgreSQL is the publisher?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, replication, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication

Is there a native way to setup transactional replication where an Azure SQL database is the subscriber and the publisher database is in Oracle?

What if the publisher database is in PostgreSQL?

If there's no native way for either of these, is there a not-so-hacky way to do it?